# Increase field by value

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

First of, my code:

```
$LogOut = $DB->prepare("UPDATE users SET online = '0', last_online = '$time', times_logged_in = times_logged_in + 1, time_spent_online = time_spent_online + $TimeSpent WHERE id = '$sessid'");
```

My problem is the last update "time_spent_online = time_spent_online + $TimeSpent" how am I supposed to format it? I can't write the number in plain because the number varies depending on how long the user was online.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't have a a field `time_spent_online`. Instead you should calculate this time on the fly whenever it is requested (and of course cache the results when needed).

In another table you will need to record each time the user logs in. From this table then you can simply calculate an estimate of the time spent online

Answer (score 0):

how about adding minutes

```
time_spent_online = time_spent_online + interval $TimeSpent minute
```